# How to detect changes in a time series data using Spark streaming

Tags: time-series, spark-streaming

I have a continuous stream of data in Kafka. I want to count the number of times a column value in the stream of data has changed.

Which algorithm I should be using for this?

Comment: Look into stateful transformations, such as `mapWithState` which can aggregate results across microbatches.

Comment: Sure, will take a look. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
Compare previous value with the current and filter out scenarios where current equals previous. After this do a count.

```
    case class TimeSeriesEntry(
      key: String,
      timestamp: Instant,
      value: Long
    )
    val timeSeriesData: Dataset[TimeSeriesEntry] = null
    timeSeriesData
      .groupByKey(_.key)
      .mapGroups { (k, timeSeriesEntries: Iterator[TimeSeriesEntry]) =>
        val last = timeSeriesEntries.next()
        if (!timeSeriesEntries.hasNext) {
          (k, true)
        } else {
          val secondLast = timeSeriesEntries.next()
          (k, last != secondLast)
        }
      }.filter {
      _._2
    }.groupByKey(_._1)
      .count()
```